Eigenvalue spectrum of bulk + low-rank matrix
I am in a position where I need to analyze the eigenspectrum of some high-dimensional square matrix $M$. A research paper I am looking at decomposes $M$ into
$$M = M_{\mathrm{bulk}} + M_{\mathrm{low-rank}}$$
where $M_{\mathrm{low-rank}}$ is some low-rank matrix. The authors say that $M_{\mathrm{bulk}}$ generates the 'bulk' of the spectrum and $M_{\mathrm{low-rank}}$ can contribute only an intensive-number of 'outlier eigenvalues' (then concludes that they will focus on the spectrum of the 'bulk matrix'). I am not familiar with such an analysis of the spectrum. Is there a general method of dealing with such a setup?

Keywords Matrix perturbation theory
